# WHOIS server daemon

Tags: linux, daemon, redhat, whois

Is there any WHOIS server daemons to run on my serer and serve My requests?

Is it possible to deploy own WHOIS server in the end of WHOIS hierarchy like DNS servers are?

Comment: There is no "whois hierarchy", this does not exist in the protocol (RFC3912). For more explanations see my detailed answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/407030/211833

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [rwhois](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2167). It is, at the very least, recognized by ARIN, and you may or may not be able to get your domain registrar to forward whois requests to you. But if they will, you can run an rwhois server that will provide whois information that is appended to the end.

Comment: @jon-lin the link for rwhois 404's, may want to update that please.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at https://github.com/DaKnOb/mwhois for a full RFC complient whois server. Plus somewhere's on sunsite there use to be a copy of nsca's whois server along with the whois client.

But do keep in mind if one is to run their own whois server most whois clients are not going to find it since by default queries for domain names goto icann/verisign as defined by arin the governing body for whois, IP addresses, ASN, reverse dns, and public routing tables.

The good news is if one is on linux then they can add TLDs to /etc/whois.conf or set the default whois in jwhois to leverage whois/whois++/rwhois servers in ones own control.