# How can I set apache to listen 43 port

Tags: apache, ubuntu, debian

I am trying set up my own whois server, that user can request by command

```
whois -h mywhois.server domain.com
```

I inserted in apache.conf Listen 43 and created vhost like this

```
<VirtualHost *:43>
    ServerName whois.test.dev
    DocumentRoot /var/www/whois.test.dev
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

But when I request via terminal it returns bad request, with other ports i  t works normal (e.g. 8080)
What is the problem with that

Answer (score 0):

It's wrong configuration for WHOIS because `Whois` it's service like an `apache` or `nginx`.
By default whois using 43 port for sending answers for whois-requests and you can't assign 43 for the web server **virtual host** (actually you can but it won't be works).

Answer (score 0):

Whois doesn't use the http protocol for answering questions... A webserver wouldn't know what to do with the traffic coming from a whois query.

There are web-based whois lookups.... but they just work as a gateway to a backend lookup to a real whois query.

If you want to run a whois service, you need to install a whois implementation like for example rwhois, see for example: [WHOIS server daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12104243/whois-server-daemon)